# Blindly call functions, catch and deal with exceptions or write code to prevent the execution of a function that would throw an exception

Tags: c#, exception

So I was wondering what the better practice was when it comes to dealing with exceptions that might get thrown in your code.

Lets say for example I have a list of items. Should I check to see if the element at 'i' exists before I try to access it? (If list.Count > i), or should I just let the code execute, and catch the exception if it gets thrown?

I've always done the former, where I would write checks to ensure functions wont get called if I knew it would throw an exceptions. (Bounds checks, null checks, etc). But now that I really think about it, aren't I just doubling up on code? The List class already does bounds checks for me and it throws the appropriate exceptions. Why am I doing a bounds check too? I could just save myself the work, blindly call the function, catch the exception and act accordingly.

Which way is 'more correct' ?

Comment: Exception handling is always costly. So it is better to proactively checking some conditions and avoid calling/performing a task that may result an exception. BUT, if you start checking every single thing, you will end up with a huge chunk of code doing only various checking, which may be very difficult maintain/read. If there are any "correct" way to handle this kind cases, even I would like to know :-)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on if you have a good way of handling the case of there not being an element `i` or not.

If you do not have a good way of handling it that makes sense for your case, or if you really don't expect the case to happen, do not write extra code around it, just let it fail. If you write good tests, these will point the way to cases you need to handle and ones you do not.

## Some examples of handling

You might want to use a default value, because maybe it doesn't matter if there's nothing there, it's a common, expected and handled case:

```
public Item GetItem(int i)
{
  if(list.Count>i)
    return list[i];
  else
    return null; //default value, could be an Item if that makes sense, see Null Object Pattern
}
```

Or, you might want to throw a more meaningful custom exception if you need to catch it somewhere (but do not use exceptions for normal program flow, it should be an exceptional case):

```
public Item GetItem(int i)
{
  if(list.Count>i)
    return list[i];
  else
    throw new NoItemException();
}
```

Or, you might want to just set a more meaningful exception message, for you or maybe a user/support guy:

```
public Item GetItem(int i)
{
  if(list.Count>i)
    return list[i];
  else
    throw new Exception("There was no element found in the list of X at " + i);
}
```

Comment: In your first example, what about just doing a try catch, and returning null on catch. List does the bounds checking for you and throws an exception.

Comment: You could, but I would only do that as a last resort. Mainly because I'd have to look up what exception type to catch as I wouldn't want to catch all.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is that *exceptions* should only be thrown for *exceptional* cases, and other cases should be handled by local error-checking.

How to determine if a case is exceptional? It really comes down to the assumptions of your code (which should be documented).

If your code assumes that when someone asks it for an element *explicitly* at index `i`, he must be sure that an element exists at that index (which is a very reasonable assumption by the way), then it should throw an exception if index `i` does not exist, because that really shouldn't happen and is considered exceptional.

Compare that to when someone asks your code to return an element with a value of "Foo". Here it's not reasonable for your code to assume that such element must exist (because the caller is really querying, without knowing about your inner implementation detail, *i.e.* indexes), and if the element is not found, that's not considered exceptional at all, so instead of throwing an exception, you return null.

If in doubt, it's always better to err on the side of error-checking rather than throwing exceptions, because exceptions are relatively expensive to handle, taking hundreds
of clock cycles, and they break program control flow, increasing its complexity.

Answer (score 0):

> should I just let the code execute, and catch the exception if it gets
>   thrown?

NO, not at all and that's exactly known as `Abusing Exception Handling`. When you already know that something may go wrong which can be fixed or checked; then why not do that validation first rather wrapping it around a `try .. catch` construct.

For example, You could do the below

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number");
try
{
int num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
}
//if someone enter a `string` in place of Integer, it will cause
catch(InvalidFormatException ix) 
{
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
}
```

This can be easily avoided by doing a check and using `TryParse()` method like

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number");
int num;
if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out num))
 {

 }
else
 {
   Console.WriteLine("Not a valid integer number");
 }
```